# Flex: when hiding components in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

When I set a component to visible=false the component hides, but how do I get it to take no space (get the container it belongs to to resize??)

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
...
</mx:HBox>

<mx:HBox width="100%" id="boxAddComment" visible="false" >
    <mx:TextArea id="txtComment"/>
    <mx:Button label="Spara" click="addComment();"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

When boxAddComment is visible=false I want the first HBox to take 100% height.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use the **includeInLayout** property. e.g.

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
...
</mx:HBox>

<mx:HBox width="100%" id="boxAddComment" visible="false" includeInLayout="false" >
    <mx:TextArea id="txtComment"/>
    <mx:Button label="Spara" click="addComment();"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Answer (score 14):

Using `includeInLayout ="true"` or `"false"` will toggle the space that it takes in the flow of items being rendered in that section.

**Important note:** If you don't specify `visible="false"` when using `includeInLayout = "false"` then you will usually get something that is undesired which is that your item (`boxAddComment`) is still visible on the page but stuff below `id="boxAddComment"` will overlap it visually. So, in general, you probably want "`includeInLayout`"  and "`visible`" to be in synch.

Comment: This can be a nice way to keep the two values in sync:  `<mx:HBox id="boxAddComment" visible="false" includeInLayout="{boxAddComment.visible}" >`

Answer (score 1):

Ross Henderson's suggestion in binding includeInLayout with boxAddComment.visible works great with Flex 3.0 but I found that it's not working in Flex 3.6 (I saw a posting that it actually stops working since Flex 3.3).

Just fyi.